# C# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)

Tags: c#, .net, image, exception, itext

I am using some 3rd party tool (itextsharp) to put images into a pdf.

after deploying the code to dev machine and passing in some images

i keep getting this error

```
error: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
```

locally in my machine it works perfectly

here is a sample snapshot of my code

```
 foreach (byte[] doc in documents.Select(c => c.Content))
 {

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(doc))
    {
       ms.Position = 0;

       var bm = new Bitmap(ms); //WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING

    //put image in pdf document
    }
}
```

SOLUTION

The solution to fix this issue is to deploy to an iis server > 7.0.0

I deployed it to 7.5.6200 and my issue dispeapred

Comment: Are all of the contents streams actually bitmaps?  I would try using `Image.FromStream` instead.

Comment: The only reason of this error is that the stream is not valid. You can set a break point at the `new Bitmap` line to see the value of `doc`.

Comment: While it is great you found a solution, you should not edit it into the question but instead create an answer with that information and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

The solution to fix this issue is to deploy to an iis server > 7.0.0

I deployed it to 7.5.6200 and my issue dispeapred